# Volume of the solid between these two parabaloids - can someone verify my answer?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I wish to find the volume of the solid bounded by the surfaces: $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $z = 4 - a^2x^2 - a^2y^2$.

I set the two surfaces equal and it gave me a circle, so, I used cylindrical co-ordinates with $z$ running from a lowest point of $0$ (as $z = x^2 + y^2$) with the largest value of $z$ being $r^2$ after substitution ($x = rcos(\theta), y= rsin(\theta)$) simply by replacing $z = x^2 + y^2$ with the substituted values for $x$ and $y$.

So, I said that:

$ 0 \leq z \leq r^2$

$0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{\frac{4}{a^2 + 1}}$

$0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$

Then:

$\displaystyle \int^{\sqrt{\frac{4}{a^2 + 1}}}_{0} \int^{2 \pi}_{0} \int^{r^2}_{0} r \ dz \ d\theta \ dr = \frac{8\pi}{(a^2 + 1)^2}$

Would somebody kindly be able to calculate the integral using their own method of choice and check if my answer is correct, as I'm not sure if I correctly used cylindrical co-ordinates here.

Thanks!

Comment: I could easily be wrong, but I believe the answer is $\frac{8\pi}{a^2+1}$.

Comment: I added information about the bounds I used. Would you take a look and tell me if you spot an error? Also, what method did you use to calculate this? Thanks!

Comment: My answer is $\frac{8\pi}{(a^2 + 1)^2}$, did I either make a mistake in my bounds or did you lose a power somewhere?

Comment: I believe you want $r^2\le z\le 4-a^2r^2$, since $z=r^2$ is the surface on the bottom and $z=4-a^2r^2$ is the one on the top.

Comment: Ah I see, that was my mistake. It was an exam question from an exam I did today. Hopefully I get some attempt marks at least...

Comment: Probably you will, since the rest of your integral is set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciated! :)